# Convert permalink to SEO fiendly permalink with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how to convert permalink

> 'watch.php?a=RANDOMTEXT1&e=RANDOMTEXT2'

to

> 'watch/a/RANDOMTEXT1/e/RANDOMTEXT2.html'

with php preg_replace if RANDOMTEXT1 and RANDOMTEXT2 is random text?

Answer (score 0):

You could use e.g. this regex:

```
(watch)\.php\?(a)=([^&]+)&(e)=([^&]+)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1/$2/$3/$4/$5.html
```

But it really depends on your requirements. Is this the only example where you need to create a link like this? You could also simplify the regex and only use `watch\.php\?a=([^&]+)&e=([^&]+)` and replace it with `watch/a/$1/e/$2.html`. If you want the regex to also allow `&` character, but only if they are not followed by an equal sign `=`, you would need to use negative lookaheads.

Here is the live example: https://regex101.com/r/jdRaok/1